# How does the Backup from the admin control panel work

Tags: backup, admin-panel

> **Hello everyone I'm a newbie!**
>
> How do I make a backup from the admin control panel?
>
> I clicked both
> System Backup Database and Database and Media and I left it to work,
> but then the main backups screen doesn't show any results. Where are
> they saved? How can I downlaod them?

Thanks

Comment: it's not reproducable

Answer (score 3):

See the screenshot:

After Backup file path

> var\backups

hear store.

1) assign your backupname.
[image]

2) after create click on .gz format.

[image]

3) [image]

If generate error on backup time:

1. What I'm doing is changed the PEAR file permissions to 755
   (public_html/lib/PEAR).
2. To change the PEAR file permissions, I need to go thru my File
   Manager on hosting cpanel.
3. I have no idea why i cannot change the PEAR file permissions thru
   FTP.
4. It give me "550 Could not change perms on PEAR: Permission denied".

   Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ok, I'm stucked on the second screenshot, it doesn't display the green message "the backup has been created". The website is on an external server (and the admin cp log me out automatically every ten minutes), I don't know if this has nothing to do with it

Comment: var\backups file backup path.